# Changing and accessing global var in flutter/dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I am very new to Dart/Flutter, but I am trying to learn and understand. Here is my issue:
I got global.dart that stores global vars and I know how to access and to change them, but I want a separate class to update itself when a global var is changed from a different class. These classes are stored in different files.

I am not sure if any code is needed in this question..

Comment: Check out [this](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple). You can have a `ChangeNotifierProvider` at the top of your widget tree, access the members for anywhere in the widget tree, and also listen to changes automatically with `Consumer`.

Comment: Sorry, I checked, but I still need an example.. All I am trying to achieve is a bool that can be changed on the main page, and other pages to be changed automatically when this bool is changed

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirement, what you need is called [`ChangeNotifier`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/ChangeNotifier-class.html) and you can use a [`Provider`](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) to provide the variables of the `ChangeNotifier` in any file they are required.

Before using the ChangeNotifiers (can be multiple, like NewsProvider, FeedProvider, CommentProvider etc), you've to inject it into the widget cycle before the Widget/Component you intend to use it in. For that, check the widget `Provider` or `MultiProvider` in the Provider linked above.

After setting up the ChangeNotifiers and injecting them into the widget cycle, you can use them in any widget or class as:

1. For one-time reading the value, use read as:

   ```
   SampleNotifier sample = context.read<SampleNotifier>();
   print(sample.variableName);
   ```

   Also, in `onClick` triggered functions, you can't use `watch`, only `read` is allowed, as these functions are static in nature and doesn't require dynamically updated value. Also, when you want to access and call a function declared in a `ChangeNotifier`, for example the `setSignIn` mentioned below, use `read`.
2. For listening to the changes in the variables of the provider, use watch as:

   ```
   SampleNotifier sample = context.watch<SampleNotifier>();
   print(sample.variableName);
   ```

Above mentioned `read` and `watch` are not the actual functions provided by the package `Provider` but their short form as extension function on `context` and you don't need both, this one's enough and better.

A sample `ChangeNotifer`:

```
class SampleNotifier extends ChangeNotifier {
  //A locally-scoped sample variable
  bool _isUserLoggedIn = false;

  //Getter to  get the sample value
  bool get isUserLoggedIn => _isUserLoggedIn;

  //Contructor sample to initialize the variables with the default values
  //You can initialize it with the global values in your global vars file
  FabNotifier() {
    _isUserLoggedIn = false;
  }

  //Sample function to perform some logic and set the updated value
  setSignIn() {
    _isUserLoggedIn = true;
    //To notify all the classes listening to this variable, to update the usage there
    //watch is used to listen to the value, so wherever watch is used, it will update the value
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

To inject this `SampleNotifier`, check the `Provider`/`MultiProvider` in the linked Provide package above and to use it, check the `read` or `watch` mentioned above.